# Create a QgsProject without opening it

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I could find a method to do that. Suppose you have a list of QGIS project paths and you want to get the project information, like the loaded layers, canvas extent, etc from the project.

I thought the easiest way to do it was to create a `QgsProject` object and then with all the methods, grad the information needed.

The `read` method of [`QgsProject`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProject.html#qgis.core.QgsProject.read) creates a `QgsProject` from a path, **BUT** it also opens the project in QGIS. Is there a simple way to create a `QgsProject` object **without** also opening it?

Comment: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Qgis.html#qgis.core.Qgis.ProjectReadFlag
Using the flags you should be able to do what you want

Comment: Oh thanks! Wasn't aware of the project flags!